# Bannerslider module "Incorrect dependency in class" error

Tags: magento-2.1, module, third-party-module

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop. To achieve this, I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

I have installed the **[Bannerslider module](https://www.magestore.com/banner-slider-on-magento2.html)**.

I run the commands:

1. php bin/magento module:enable Magestore_Bannerslider
2. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
3. php bin/magento setup:di:compile

All was ok in my local development environment, but on **staging environment** I get an error `Incorrect dependency in class Magestore\Bannerslider\Controller\Index in /var/www/staging.domain.com/app/code/Magestore/Bannerslider/Controller/Index.php
\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface already exists in context object` in the console.

Also, `Error log record number: 1455276823131` error in the browser (frontend).

Why is that? What is the fix? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in your **_construct function**

`$this->_objectManager = $context->getObjectManager();`

> /var/www/staging.domain.com/app/code/Magestore/Bannerslider/Controller/Index.php

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magestore\Bannerslider\Model\SliderFactory $sliderFactory,
    \Magestore\Bannerslider\Model\BannerFactory $bannerFactory,
    \Magestore\Bannerslider\Model\ReportFactory $reportFactory,
    \Magestore\Bannerslider\Model\ResourceModel\Report\CollectionFactory $reportCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog $monolog,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone $stdTimezone
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_sliderFactory = $sliderFactory;
    $this->_bannerFactory = $bannerFactory;
    $this->_reportFactory = $reportFactory;
    $this->_reportCollectionFactory = $reportCollectionFactory;
    $this->_resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory;
    $this->_monolog = $monolog;
    $this->_stdTimezone = $stdTimezone;
    $this->_objectManager = $context->getObjectManager(); // Add this line
}
```

Comment: my file has *this* code: `$this->_stdTimezone = $stdTimezone;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;`. Shall I *replace* the last line with `$this->_objectManager = $context->getObjectManager();`?

Comment: yes please... also check this link https://github.com/Magestore/Bannerslider-Magento2/pull/90/files?diff=split

Comment: And the run the commands again> Which one?

Comment: just clear the cache and check again. It should work

Comment: But it works in the local environment *as it is*,  without the changes you are suggesting. But *not* on staging. Why?

Comment: Shall I clear cache fon the command line? How?

Comment: I get this error: *There has been an error processing your request*. In the frontend only.

Comment: what did you do?

Comment: I have updated that index file, disabled the module then run those 3 commands in the issue description.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69013/discussion-between-abhishek-panchal-and-razvan-zamfir).